# Get specific attribute for each product on catalog page

Tags: attributes

On catalog page, I want to display custom attribute near each product (e.g. `shoes_model`). When I try to fetch it:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('shoes_model'); // returns nothing
```

... it returns empty value. But when I try to get another attribute, e.g. `brand`, it returns correct value:

```
$_product->getAttributeText('brand'); // returns brand name
```

Can anyone explain why is this happening and how to include custom attribute in catalog products collection.

p.s. Option "Used in Product Listing" is set to Yes for both attributes, and I'm 100% sure that `shoes_model` is defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything was simpler than I thought, as `shoes_model` is text-based attribute, I should get it like so:

```
$_product->getShoesModel();
```

or like so:

```
$_product->getData('shoes_model');
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this code

```
 $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('custom_attribute_code');
    if ($attribute)
    {
        echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

<?php echo $_product->getData('attributename'); ?>
```

And also make sure you have included the attributes in layout, and that they are set to "visible on frontend".

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product 
    $shoes = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('shoes_model')->getFrontend()->getValue($product); ?>
```

Now you can use this variable `$shoes` anywhere you like

Hope it will work for you.