# Magento 2 : How to display custom values under product on cart page?

Tags: magento2, custom-options, shopping-cart

I have manually added one combo box on product view page. Now when customer add that product to the cart, I want to display selected combo box value on cart page.

Please refer my below screen shot to get a better idea.

[image]

Comment: Please see: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110531/get-product-attribute-in-cart-in-magento2

Comment: @tecjam I want to override \Magento\Downloadable\Block\Checkout\Cart\Item\Renderer for this purpose. So can you please help me. Your given link is not useful to me.

Comment: I do not think you need to override the renderer - actually you could do all of this directly in the template I have overridden in the above link. In the template you are given the options `<?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>` - this gives you the Downloads: Episode 3 output. Now do anything you want afterwards.

Comment: @tecjam this is only useful for downloadable product type.But what for else ?