# Checkout Page List Item Add Custom Attribute

Tags: magento2

We have a custom product level attribute created in the Catalog. Whenever product added to the Cart, using events/Observer, I could bring down the custom attribute value to Quote.item. Now I need to display that value (if present) in the Checkout Page List View.  Any idea how to do that ?

**

> our Custom Attribute/Div needs to apprear right after Size:

** 
[image: our Custom Attribute/Div needs to apprear right after Size:]

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and this post worked for me: [Get product attribute in cart in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110531/get-product-attribute-in-cart-in-magento2)

You basically create a custom module with a helper class and reference it in your default.phtml