# Add custom product attribute to checkout summary Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, knockoutjs

I am trying to add a custom product attribute to the list of items on the summary section in the checkout in Magento 2. The template file is at `Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/item/details.html` and looking to display the value of the custom attribute before the product name. Any idea on how this value is added to the ko template? Looks like there is another question for this [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119789/magento2-how-can-i-display-a-product-attribute-value-in-order-summary-block) but was never answered.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116642/checkout-page-list-item-add-custom-attribute

Comment: @Arjun This is different. This referenced article really shows the cart page not checkout. The cart is a simple phtml template. The checkout is a ko page and is getting its source from somewhere else than the mini-cart. Not sure why all cart items displayed in mini cart, cart, and checkout all are built in different ways. But the actual checkout summary is where I need to see how to add the custom attribute.

Comment: @sudopratt, Have you get idea about that, How to add a custom product attribute to the list of items on the summary section in the checkout in Magento 2 ?

Answer (score 22):

You will have to create a plugin for that. I wanted to add product flavor to order summary. This is the way I created a plugin and achieved what I wanted.

**Vendor = Sejal**

Files you need to create:

1. Registration.php : `app\code\Sejal\Flavor\registration.php`
2. di.xml : `app\code\Sejal\Flavor\etc\di.xml`
3. module.xml : `app\code\Sejal\Flavor\etc\module.xml`
4. ConfigProviderPlugin.php : `app\code\Sejal\Flavor\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin.php`
5. details.html : copy of `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html`

you can override this file in your theme like this

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\themename\Magento_Checkout\web\template\summary\item\details.html
```

Code:
**registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sejal_Flavor',
    __DIR__
);
```

di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="AddAttPlug" type="Sejal\Flavor\Plugin\ConfigProviderPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sejal_Flavor" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

ConfigProviderPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace Sejal\Flavor\Plugin;

class ConfigProviderPlugin extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
    {

        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){

            $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
            $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteId);
            $productId = $quote->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $productFlavours = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('flavors')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);         
            if($productFlavours == 'No' || $productFlavours == 'NA'){
                $productFlavours = '';
            }
            $items[$i]['flavor'] = $productFlavours;
        }
        $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
        return $result;
    }

}
```

**details.html**

```
Copy vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html
```

in theme and add

```
<div class="product-item-flavor" data-bind="text: $parent.flavor"></div>
```

below

```
<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
```

That's it! 
Hope it helps!

Comment: I have tried in Aheadworks onestepcheck extension but its not working. How can i do ?

Comment: @Sejal Shah please answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279918/how-to-add-a-additional-field-in-summary-section-magento-2-3

Comment: @Sejal Shah
how to add if condition here

Comment: This works great for the shipping step, but on the billing step .product-item-flavor stays empty

Comment: Sejal answered my question here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178398/adding-custom-attribute-to-checkout-order-summary-not-reflecting-on-payment-page?rq=1

Comment: @Sejal is not working with magento 2.3.5 version

Comment: @ManishMaheshwari for Aheadworks onestepcheck extension. You need to modify these files. 

1) app/code/Aheadworks/OneStepCheckout/etc/di.xml

2) app/code/Aheadworks/OneStepCheckout/Plugin/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php

3) app/design/frontend/Myvendor/Mytheme/Aheadworks_OneStepCheckout/web/js/view/sidebar/item-details.js

4) app/design/frontend/Myvendor/Mytheme/Aheadworks_OneStepCheckout/web/template/sidebar/sidebar/item-details.html

Comment: after using the plugin data is showing into the console json this is my HTML code    <div class="product-item-waste" data-bind="text: $parent.waste_cost"></div> it is also showing on the console but my attribute is not showing into the checkout summary  waste_cost

Answer (score 4):

if you want to add your custom attribute in order summary you need to override:
(Layouts)
1) checkout_cart_index :

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="processingfee" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Dedicated_Processingfee/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/processingfee</item>
                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Dedicated_Processingfee/checkout/cart/totals/processingfee</item>
                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Processing Fee</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

2) checkout_index_index :

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                            <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="processingfee" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Dedicated_Processingfee/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/processingfee</item>
                                                        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Dedicated_Processingfee/checkout/cart/totals/processingfee</item>
                                                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Processing Fee</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                            <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/item/details/subtotal</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

3) sales_order_view :

```
<referenceContainer name="order_totals">
        <block class="Dedicated\Processingfee\Block\Sales\Order\ProcessingFee" name="processingfee"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

then add custom js to get your custom attribute value like this in your module :  at /view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/processingfee.js:

```
define(
[
    'Dedicated_Processingfee/js/view/checkout/summary/processingfee'
],
function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({

        /**
        * @override
        */
        isDisplayed: function () {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

);

add another js to calculate value with total billing amount in : /view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/processingfee.js

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals'
],
function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals) {
    "use strict";
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed: window.checkoutConfig.isFullTaxSummaryDisplayed || false,
            template: 'Dedicated_Processingfee/checkout/summary/processingfee'
        },
        totals: quote.getTotals(),
        isTaxDisplayedInGrandTotal: window.checkoutConfig.includeTaxInGrandTotal || false,
        isDisplayed: function() {
            return this.isFullMode();
        },
        getValue: function() {
            var price = 0;
            if (this.totals()) {
                price = totals.getSegment('processingfee').value;
            }
            return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
        },
        getBaseValue: function() {
            var price = 0;
            if (this.totals()) {
                price = this.totals().base_fee;
            }
            return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getBasePriceFormat());
        }
    });
}
```

);

That set you will find you attribute with value Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: I dont think @sudopratt wants to add a row in totals coumn rather a product attribute below product name like short description.

Comment: @ Sunil Verma  have you got a solution for this . I need to do exactly same but cant get any reference

Comment: Yes, its show custom attribute but when move to next step for #payment then custom attribute disappear. why?

Comment: Could you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59243164/enable-payment-gateway-for-particular-products-magento-2

Answer (score 1):

For me was *$result['totalsData']['items']* empty. 
I have used following implementation instead:

```
public function afterGetConfig(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject,
    array $result

) {
    foreach ($result['quoteItemData'] as $index => $itemData) {
        $product = $this->productRepository->getById($itemData['product_id']);
        $result['quoteItemData'][$index]['flavor'] = $product->getFlavor();
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to display simple product name of the configurable. So I used code as below. But same simple name is displaying when I choose same configurable options in the checkout order summary. So How I display correct simple product names?

```
public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, array $result)
{

    $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    for($i=0;$i<count($items);$i++){

        $quoteId = $items[$i]['item_id'];
        $quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item')->load($quoteId);
        $productId = $quote->getProductId();
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
        $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
        $usedProducts = $productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product);

        foreach ($usedProducts  as $child) {
            $childName = $child->getName(); //Child Product Name
        }           

        $items[$i]['childname'] = $childName;
    }
    $result['totalsData']['items'] = $items;
    return $result;
}
```