# Adding a product attribute in checkout summary

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout

I am having an attribute which needs to be there along with the product name. I want to add it in checkout summary area. 
Please see the image below

Need to override this page:

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html

```
<div class="product-item-name-block">
    <!-- want to add a Product_attribute Here -->
    <h4 data-bind="text:$parent.some_product_attribue_value"></h4>
     <!-- want to add a Product_attribute Here -->
    <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
    <div class="details-qty">
        <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Qty' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.qty"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You could use this answer to show your attribute: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/178391/47624