# Add custom product attribute to checkout summary Magento -2

Tags: magento2, module

I have added onestepCheckout module in my project. Now, I want to show discount amount in checkout summary after product name.

I refer this link : [Add custom product attribute to checkout summary Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132746/add-custom-product-attribute-to-checkout-summary-magento-2)

It shows something on that page while loading. But when my page loaded properly then it's gone.

Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Here you can see this '**no**' below item image 
 is showing while loading and then disappears. :  https://www.loom.com/share/ab05cd107b384d468b2d1147816c2ae6

Comment: Have you check consol or error log file?

Comment: yes, i have checked consol : http://prntscr.com/nh29j7

Comment: /vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml  <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
   <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/cart/totals/discount</item>
   <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Discount</item>
   </item>
</item>   Insert it in checkout_cart_index.xml file of Magento_checkout in your theme by Overriding it there.

Now you can see discount try it @KhooshbuPatel

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it's not working because I have added OnestepCheckout module.@sannikalariya