# How to add a div in summary magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-field, checkout-summary

I need to add a div inside the summary section. please guide me how to achieve the expected result. Also please check with below image to view summary section.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hey, Please check with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132746/add-custom-product-attribute-to-checkout-summary-magento-2 this url

Comment: Summary page bind with knockoutJS right?, so above urls answer in enough for my expected result ?

Comment: yes, Its work for you. 100%, also if you want to add only lable or message than goto html file and put the lable.

Comment: okay, let me check .

Answer (score 3):

You can override the checkout_cart_index page:

1.Inside [vendor-name] / [module-name] / view / frontend / layout / checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="CustomData" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">[vendor-name_module-name]/js/checkout/cart/totals/customdata</item>
                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                         <item name="template" xsi:type="string">[vendor-name_module-name]/checkout/cart/totals/customdata</item>
                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Data</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

2.Create a js file under [vendor-name_module-name] / view / frontend / web / js / checkout / cart / totals / customdata.js with

```
define([

        'uiComponent'
       ],
        function (Component){
                 'use strict'; 
                  return Component.extend({});
    });
```

3.Create a html file under [vendor-name_module-name] / view / frontend / web / template / checkout / cart / totals / customdata.html

```
<tr class="totals">
  <th class="mark" scope="row">
    <div>This is a div element</div>
  </th>   
</tr>
```

The Result will be

[image: checkout]

Hope this will be help you

Comment: No way :(  ,when add this module site  takes more time to executes

Comment: I am also executed that it doesn't take much time. You may try that code in new module

Comment: Nop..!  Element not visible

Comment: Did you try it in new module

Comment: Yes , But No changes

Comment: Is any error in console?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below url -

[Add custom product attribute to checkout summary Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132746/add-custom-product-attribute-to-checkout-summary-magento-2)

If you want to add label or message than override below html file `checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html`

I hope its work for you.

Comment: can you please check with your theme files, i tried from my side, its working for me.

Comment: No way brother , this not work for me !!!!!!!!

Comment: Try with this directory - vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/