# I want to show total qty of items instead of number of item in cart

Tags: magento2, cart

[image]

I want to show total qty of items instead of number of item in cart

Comment: please try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/280374/how-to-add-a-div-in-summary-magento-2

Comment: use this helper to print total quantity  <?php echo $cartCount = $this->helper('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getItemsCount(); ?>

Comment: i have added answer its working for me. also thanks to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to below steps to show the total quantity of the items.

**Go to Store ->Configuration ->Catalog ->Catalog ->My Cart Link ->Display Cart Summary -> (and choose) Display Items Quantities**

Clear the cache and Refresh

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I want to show total qty of items instead of number of item in cart  check solution
its working :)