# How to get the value of an EAV attribute from a model class in Magento2

Tags: magento2, model, eav

I have got an object of this model magento/catalog/model/product and I want to use one of the EAV attributes values of it. How to access this EAV attribute through model object.There is no issue with non-EAV attributes to be used.

Comment: Please check the solution is this post ;) [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110531/get-product-attribute-in-cart-in-magento2/251485#251485](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110531/get-product-attribute-in-cart-in-magento2/251485#251485)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use code like:

```
$product = $productRepo->get($productId); 
$attributeValueId = $product->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute_code');
```

Comment: I'm manipulating a helper in magento2 core. There, I already have have that loaded product. I also want to have access to EAV product attributes. what shall I do then?

Comment: you can use $product->getCustomAttribute('my_custom_attribute_code'); but if product loaded not from repo, attribute will not be loaded

Comment: the product does not load from repo! it has been loaded from magento/catalog/model/product. So how can I load EAV attribute? Is there any appropriate solution?

Comment: @AminMemariani try `$product->getData('attribute_code');`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new helper, add the product repository in the constructor and get eav custom attributes from here.
Please check details in this post :
[Get product attribute in cart in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110531/get-product-attribute-in-cart-in-magento2/251485#251485)