# get specific option value and label

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart, magento-community

In the `default.phtml` for the checkout cart this is used to get all options:

```
<?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>
    <dl class="item-options">
        <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
           <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
        <dt><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
        <dd>
            <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_formatedOptionValue['value'] ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
<?php endif;?>
```

But how do I get one specific option with value and label by its code?

I added that option in the backend. There it is called attribute suddenly  for some reason. And there are also some functions to get attributes but neither of them returns anything other than null if I try to use it on the `$product` in `default.phtml`.
I also tried to fetch it in the same matter it is fetched in `->getOptionList()` but that also returns nothing else than null.
Here are some things I tried in the head of `default.phtml`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer */

$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();

$optionIds = $_item->getOptionByCode('option_ids'); // null
$addOptions = $_item->getOptionByCode('additional_options'); // null

$option = $product->getOptionById(140); // null
$customOption = $product->getCustomOption('mycode'); // null
$customAttribute = $product->getCustomAttribute('mycode'); // null
$customOptions = $product->getCustomOptions(); // does not contain it
$options = $product->getOptions(); // null
$data = $product->getData(); // doesn't contain it either
```

Trying to add more data hoping this might help someone spot where it is breaking...

Here is how the attribute is setup:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'mycode',
    [
        'type' => 'int',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'My Code',
        'input' => 'select',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'global' => 1,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default' => null,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => 'configurable',
        'system' => 1,
        'group' => 'General',
        'option' => array('values' => array("x","y"))
    ]
);
```

Comment: Please see this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110531/get-product-attribute-in-cart-in-magento2

Comment: those don't work