# magento 2: get configurable product custom attributes at checkout/confirmation page

Tags: magento2

I have configurable product with custom attributes (not front end visible) 
I get the $item from when looping over $items.
I'm getting $items like so:

```
$itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

$y = $item->getProduct()->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_id')->getFrontend()->getValue($item->getProduct());
```

The trouble is I can't see the attribute's value, i see all the meta data about the attribute, but not the value relvant to the item. I need to access that attribute on the checkout and confirmation steps of the order placement.

When accessing the same element on the PDP page I get it with no problems:

```
$x = (int) $product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_attribute_id')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

I stepped through both cases with xdebug, but just can't figure it out.

Comment: This thread will help you [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110531/get-product-attribute-in-cart-in-magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110531/get-product-attribute-in-cart-in-magento2)

Comment: ... @Iyappan Perumal spot on. I'll take your comment as the answer. I've seen the post you referred but overlooked it initially.