# Custom attribute value required in catagory page by using plugins

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to add value my custom attribute in catagory product page 
i am using this code "$temp= $subject->getCustomAttribute('option')->getValue();"
it give me  a value but value is not in my attribute it give me wrong value please help me

Comment: Is this a custom product attribute? Have you added it to your .xml in your module? Else you have to load the entire product / category .. see: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110531/get-product-attribute-in-cart-in-magento2

Comment: no its not my custom attribute i used plugin like this

Comment: <?php
     
    namespace Wahajmodule\HelloWorld\Model;

 
    class Product
    {
  
        public function afterGetName(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject, $result) {
   $temp="";
  
   if (null !== $subject->getAttribute('option')) {
   $temp= $subject->getAttribute('option')->getValue();
}
            return   $result." ".$temp." Kg ";
        }
    }